# How can I save a javascript object to mongodb without losing its methods?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, socket.io

I have a JS object deriving from a particular class with methods in it. I want to save it to an array of objects in a mongoose schema. To do it I send it with Socket.io. When I save the object on the server and then retrieve it, all the methods have gone away. Is this normal behavior?

My object is something like this:

```
class MyObject {}

MyObject.prototype.myMethod = function(){
     //Do something
}
```

My schema looks like this:

```
const ProjectSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    arrayData: {
        type: Array,
        of: Object,
        default: []
    }
})
```

My client code looks like this:

```
var object1 = new MyObject();

socket.emit('updateSend',{object1, projectId}, (error) => {
            if(error) {
                alert(error);
            } else {
                console.log('changes successfully updated');
            }
});
```

And my server:

```
socket.on('updateSend',async ({object1,projectId}, callback) => {
    try {
        const project = await ProjectSchema.findById(projectId)
        project.arrayData.push(object1)
        await project.save()

    } catch(e) {
        return callback(e)
    }
})
```

Comment: Storing methods in databases doesn't make any sense in the first place. What you need is called (de)serialization. Meaning you turn an instance of MyObject into an object that contains just the data, then store that in the database. When the object is loaded from the database, you use its data to recreate the original instance, thereby "gaining back" the methods. Serialization is typically done using a method that you call on the instance which returns a data-only version, and deserialization is usually done using a contructor that accepts the data as argument(s).

Comment: by reading [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/store-javascript-function-on-server/#store-a-javascript-function-on-the-server) in mongodb doc you can store js function and may be retrieve it by it's id

Comment: @antoineso That doesn't apply to OP's situation and is misleading

Comment: It's a database. You use it to store data, not logic.

Comment: you're right sorry I misunderstood the question

Comment: @ChrisG that makes sense, thanks!

Comment: @ChrisG you should post that as an answer